# How to center text in a line, with a button floated to it's right?

Tags: html, css

I want to accomplish a very simple layout, but am struggling. I want a header to be centered within the parent div, with a button on the floated to the right of the header (on the same line). The below code accomplishes this effect, but the button is unclickable because the header covers it. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.parent {
  border: solid 3px #000;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">My header:</div>
  <button type="button" name="abutton" class="button" onclick="alert('a');">The button!</button>
</div>
```

edit:

Fixed the code error.

Comment: I can click on the button (chrome,firefox)..Can you detail more your problem? Show us on jsfiddle.

Comment: Beware you have a html code error in the name of the button

Comment: Your styles don't match your markup.

Comment: fixed the html code error. here is the jsfiddle, it is unclickable in chrome: 
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AcR67ELlyy

Comment: Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gt5x3rc1/

Answer (score 2):

use z-index css property (and make button relatively positioned):

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button {
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. could you explain why it's necessary to make the button relatively positioned for the z-indexing to work? (if z-indexing is set, i would expect the button to be on top of the header regardless?)

Comment: well there are two types of elements: static and non-static. The second type is `position: absolute, relative and fixed`. So the `z-index` works only with non-static elements. For static elements it is simply ignored. Why `position: relative` and not others? Because it behaves really close to the static elements. That's why this is the best option if you want to change only a `z-index`. By default all elements have `position: static` property

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://jsfiddle.net/apLbkrLy/) may help you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="header">
      My header:
    <button type="button" name="abutton" class="button">The button!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  border: solid 3px #000;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
   float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `z-index` to `.header` and `.button`.

```
.header {z-index: 1;}
.button {z-index: 2; position: relative;} /* z-index is applied to positioned elements only */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way.

I'm not sure why your `header_text` is positioned absolutely but it's much easier let things flow as normal but position the button that way.

```css
.header_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.parent {
  border: solid 3px #000;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="header_text">My Header Text</h1>
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="abutton" class="button">The button!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header_text {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.parent {
  border: solid 3px #000;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header_text">My header:</div>
  <button type="button" name="abutton" class="button" onclick="alert('a');">The button!</button>
</div>
```